# Create a New List from a List of Lists and print exactly in Python

Tags: python, list

I want to create a List from a List of Lists in Python. This is my approach

```
    grid=[[0,1,1], \
          [1,0,1], \
          [1,1,1], \
          [1,0,0]]
    grid2=[]
    for x in range(0,len(grid)):
     for y in range(0,len(grid[x])):
       if grid[x][y]==0:
         grid2.append(22)
       if grid[x][y]==1:
         grid2.append(44)

    for item in grid2:print grid2
```

The output that I expected is in grid2 the list will be like this:

```
22,44,44
44,22,44
44,44,44
44,22,22
```

But it seems my logic is wrong. Need some help

Comment: I see what the code does but I don't understand what's wrong with it. please elaborate.

Comment: @Pavel Their code creates a 1-D list here, they want 2-D list.

Comment: Add `grid2.append([])` between the two for-loops and replace `grid2.append(...)`'s with `grid2[-1].append(...)`.

Comment: Thanks .. It works Perfectly @200 OK.. May be you can post it as answer so that I can vote it as correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to treat grid2 as a list of lists.  At least that's what I think you are trying to do.

```
grid=[[0,1,1], \
      [1,0,1], \
      [1,1,1], \
      [1,0,0]]
grid2=[]
for x in range(0,len(grid)):
    grid2.append([])
    for y in range(0,len(grid[x])):
        if grid[x][y]==0:
           grid2[x].append(22)
        if grid[x][y]==1:
           grid2[x].append(44)

for item in grid2:
    print ','.join([str(x) for x in item])
```

Comment: Also, I'm not saying this is the best way to do this, I am just assuming you are learning the language so showing how to fix your code is probably best.

Answer (score 1):

Your `print` loop is wrong. As written, you print `grid2` in its entirety for every item in `grid2`. You can fix it by printing `item` instead.

```
for item in grid2: print item
```

If you want to instead `print` the exact output that you specified in the question, *while keeping a 1D list*, you can borrow some code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/312464/391161) and use `",".join`.

```
def chunks(l, n):
    """ Yield successive n-sized chunks from l.
    """
    for i in xrange(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i+n]


for item in chunks(grid2, 3): print ",".join(str(x) for x in item)
```

Output:

```
22,44,44
44,22,44
44,44,44
44,22,22
```

Answer (score 0):

Your print loop is wrong.

```
for item in grid2:
    print (item)
```

You can have a much better solution using numpy:

```
a = np.array([[0,1,1],
      [1,0,1],
      [1,1,1],
      [1,0,0]])
np.where(a == 0, 22, 44)
Out[23]: 
array([[22, 44, 44],
       [44, 22, 44],
       [44, 44, 44],
       [44, 22, 22]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `for item in grid2:print grid2` with `for item in grid2:print item` (for each item you print the entire list)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
grid=[[0,1,1], \
  [1,0,1], \
  [1,1,1], \
  [1,0,0]]

grid2=[",".join(["44" if flag else "22" for flag in row]) for row in grid]
print "\n".join(grid2)
```